# WWDC 2011 sample Source code

Tags: ios

Has anyone found a place to download WWDC 2011 source code? I have downloaded the video and slides.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code wont be available for a while still, but you can check out the WWDC 2011 Session material downloader on Github, requires Ruby and have been an attendee.

https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/WWDC2011-Downloader

Comment: Thank you. It is too late for me to attend now. I would expect someone who has attended WWDc has posted the code to somewhere on the internet. But couldn't find it.

Comment: Attendees are not allowed to post code from the sessions, Apple historically releases code sometime after the final release of the new iOS, which in this case would be iOS5 which was released today. Just keep a close eye on the Apple Developer website for any updates.

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll wait for it then.